# what does [ -n "$VARIABLE" ] || exit 0 mean

Tags: bash, shell

Looking at correcting an issue in /etc/init.d/hostapd on Debian. However, I have no clue what this line of code does nor how it works

```
[ -n "$DAEMON_CONF" ] || exit 0
```

In searching online for bash tutorials, I've never seen anyone do this

When I run the code, my shell window closes (because $DAEMON_CONF is not set to anything). If I change the code to

```
[ -n "not empty" ] || exit 0
```

my console window does not close.

so, -n evaluates to true, and or'ed with exit 0, is what?

Comment: One hack when some process returns an error to silence is oring with true. So this `|| whatever` means whatever is always executed, if the "result" of the things left to the double pipe symbol evaluate to false, in shell lingo a failing exit code ... @ElliotFrisch did put it in better words

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Conditional_execution

Comment: @MarcB thanks for the link to the docs!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the expression in `[]` returns false, do the thing after the or `||` (and `exit 0`). Otherwise, it will short circuit and the next statement will be evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

`[` is and alternate name for the command `test`. You can learn about the parameters/flags whatnot by looking at test's manpage:

```
man test
```

You'll see for `-n`:

> -n STRING
>
> ```
>           the length of STRING is nonzero
> ```

Furthemore `||` means `OR`. So if the `test` command returns `False` then the stuff after the `||` will be executed. If `test` returns true, then it won't be executed.

Written out your command says: "If the variable $DAEMON_CONF lacks a value, then exit with return code 0"

The longhand version would be something like:

```
if test ! -n "$DAEMON_CONF"; then
    exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[ -n "$DAEMON_CONF" ] || exit 0
```

It's an unnecessary double negative.  This would do the same thing:

```
[ -z "$DAEMON_CONF" ] && exit 0
```

Or it could be done without *any* flag:

```
[ "$DAEMON_CONF" ] || exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It checks if the environment variable is defined, if $DAEMON_CONF is not present the it will exit with 0 code, a better code would be.

`[ -n "$DAEMON_CONF" ] || echo "exiting as DAEMON_CONF is not set" && exit 1`